# Why Showing a dialog in App() constructor prevents WPF app showing up?

Tags: c#, wpf

I used visual studio to create a new wpf application. I added a constructor for the app:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        App() : base()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("foo", "bar");
        }
    }
}
```

The application will only show the message box, then it will not show the main window after you close the message box.

However, if I make it a static constructor like:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("foo", "bar");
        }
    }
}
```

It will be able to launch the main window.

Can someone help me in understanding what's wrong with the first method?

Comment: Both are a bad idea. You shouldn't block a constructor. The reason the static doesn't block is because it's run independently of instantiating the app class.

Comment: Better override `Application.OnStartup()` to do such things. Constructor is only used to initialize the class (static) or the instance (non-static).

Answer (score 0):

Because `StartupUrl` is not set yet.

In the constructor of [System.Windows.Application](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,176), it invoke an async operation. And what we care about is [DoStartup](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,1636) method in that async operation, in which it checks if `StartupUrl` is null.

When invoke an async operation, it [post a message](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,2686) and that should be handled after you call `App.Run()`.

Calling `MessageBox.Show` needs to use the current dispatcher, then the previous inovked operation will be handled(but `StartupUrl` is not set).

For the static constructor, it is called before constructor, so no such problem exist.